# Is there a way to call 2 classes in my Java code?

Tags: java, class

So, I make class and call it Main
Then I finish what I needed to do and make a new class
I decided to call it Main2

I finish what I using the class and then I run the program, But then It only runs the first class rather than running both(Im a beginner to Java so i'm not so sure if it is supposed to be like that) Is there a reason on why it doesn't work, and what I can do to make it work

I asked on the forums on repl.it and one user told me to add this to my code

```
 class Main.2;
    Main2.run;
```

Here is my current code: https://repl.it/@JavasLava/Steel-Ball-Run

I would like for it to run the 4 print statements that I have in my classes.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA,a java file will and shuld have only one public class which named the file's name.
If you want to run the main function in two class ,you may call second main function in the first class.
Such as

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("I am learning Java");
    System.out.println("Comments are Kinda usefull");
    ......
     Main2.main(args);
  }
}
```

or

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("I am learning Java");
    System.out.println("Comments are Kinda usefull");
    ......

  }
static{
 Main2.main(null);
}
}
```